# How to take a value and add it to an array once a checkbox is selected angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an Angular application that will simulate a pizza ordering website. I am specifically trying to work on a custom pizza page. I have several checkboxes that allow the user to add toppings to their pizza. How do I add the topping to an array when they click on the checkbox?

Here is the HTML page

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Crust:</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.crust" type="radio" value="Hand Tossed" name="crust" > Hand Tossed
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.crust" type="radio" value="Pan" name="crust"> Pan
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Cheese (Mozzarella): </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.cheese" type="radio" value="Light" name="cheese"> Light
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.cheese" type="radio" value="Regular" name="cheese"> Regular
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.cheese" type="radio" value="Extra" name="cheese"> Extra
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sauce: </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.sauce" type="radio" value="None" name="sauce"> None
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.sauce" type="radio" value="Light" name="sauce"> Light
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.sauce" type="radio" value="Regular" name="sauce"> Regular
                <input [(ngModel)]="customPizza.sauce" type="radio" value="Extra" name="sauce"> Extra                
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Toppings (Choose up to 5 Toppings) </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Meats: </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Pepperoni" name="meats"> Pepperoni
            <input type="checkbox" value="Italian Sausage" name="meats"> Italian Sausage
            <input type="checkbox" value="Bacon" name="meats"> Bacon
            <input type="checkbox" value="Meatball" name="meats"> Meatball
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Ham" name="meats"> Ham
            <input type="checkbox" value="Beef" name="meats"> Beef
            <input type="checkbox" value="Pork" name="meats"> Pork
            <input type="checkbox" value="Chicken" name="meats"> Chicken

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Veggies: </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Black Olives" name="veggies"> Black Olives
            <input type="checkbox" value="GreenOlives" name="veggies"> Green Olives
            <input type="checkbox" value="Pineapple" name="veggies"> Pineapple
            <input type="checkbox" value="Onions" name="veggies"> Onions
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <input type="checkbox" value="Mushrooms" name="veggies"> Mushrooms
            <input type="checkbox" value="BananaPeppers" name="veggies"> Banana Peppers
            <input type="checkbox" value="GreenPeppers" name="veggies"> Green Peppers
            <input type="checkbox" value="Jalapenos" name="veggies"> Jalapenos
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button type="submit" (click)="createAddPizza()">Add to Cart</button>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the typescript page

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Pizza } from 'src/app/pizza';
import { CustomPizza } from 'src/app/pizza';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {ShoppingCartService} from '../../shopping-cart.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-pizza-builder',
  templateUrl: './pizza-builder.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pizza-builder.component.css'],
  
})
export class PizzaBuilderComponent implements OnInit {

  

  constructor(private serShopping: ShoppingCartService) { 
    
  }
  @Input()
    toppings: string[] = [];
    topping: string = "";
    top1: string = "";
    sauce: string = "";
    cheese: string = "";
    crust: string = "";

    custPizza = new CustomPizza();
    customPizza: Pizza = {name: 'Custom Pizza',toppings: [''],sauce:'',
    cheese:'',crust:'',desciption:'',price: 14,img:''}


   
pushToArray(top: string)
{
  this.toppings.push(top);
}




  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  createAddPizza(){
    
    this.serShopping.addPizza(this.customPizza);
    
  }
}
```

I have tried to use ngModel like with the radio button but it returns true false values. I want to add the selected toppings to the topping array but I am totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Template:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Black Olives" name="veggies" (change)="addVeggies($event, 'Black Olives')">
```

TS component:

```
addVeggies(e, value) {
  e.srcElement.checked
    ? this.veggiesArray.push(value) 
    : this.veggiesArray.splice(this.veggiesArray.indexOf(value), 1);
}
```

You can also get value from $event (e.srcElement.defaultValue) to have only one argument.